# What's wrong with this jquery loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, for-loop

To summarise briefly what I'm trying to do: I'm providing the facility for a user to view a gallery of thumbnail images, each with a corresponding download link. When the download link is clicked, I present the user with a confirmation div, and assuming the user clicks 'agree', they'll be able to proceed with the download of the full size version of the thumbnail.

To do this, I'm using a repeater to generate the thumbnails. I'm creating a unique id for each link within the 'ItemCreated' event, along with a unique hidden field that stores the relative path for the destination file for that thumbnail.

When the user clicks on the 'Download' link for the appropriate thumbnail, my code *should* select the 'agree' link, and update it's target path with the hidden field value of the item that was clicked (I hope that made sense?). This basically means whenever a 'Download' button is clicked, the 'agree' link is updated to direct you to the correct file.

The problem that I'm having however is that my 'agree' link never gets updated - it seems to point to the same file for every thumbnail.

Here's a snippet of the rendered thumbnail list:

```
<div class="download-listing">
    <div class="download">
        <img src="/img/thumb0.jpg" alt="" />
        <div id="downloadLink0" class="dl">Download</div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hf0" value="/GetImage.ashx?path=/img/0.jpg" class="hf" />                    
    </div>
    <div class="download">
        <img src="/img/thumb1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div id="downloadLink1" class="dl">Download</div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hf1" value="/GetImage.ashx?path=/img/1.jpg" class="hf" />              
    </div>
    <div class="download">
        <img src="/img/thumb2.jpg" alt="" />
        <div id="downloadLink2" class="dl">Download</div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hf2" value="/GetImage.ashx?path=/img/2.jpg" class="hf" />                    
    </div>
</div>
<input id="count" type="hidden" value="3" />
<!-- Hidden popup -->
<div id="popup">
<p><a id="close" class="bClose action">I disagree</a><a id="file-link" class="action" href="#">I agree</a></p>
</div>
```

Hopefully you can see from the above code that I'm trying to extract the hidden field path from the download that's clicked, and then update the #file-link 'href' with this value.

The Javascript/Jquery I'm using (and this is where the problem seems to be) is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < $("#count").val(); i++) { 
    var index = i;
    $("#downloadLink" + index).click(function () {
      $('#file-link').attr('href', $('#hf' + index).val());
      $('#popup').bPopup();
    });          
  }      
});
</script>
```

However, none of this is working! What seems to be happening is that every download link points to the same path - the last one in the list. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

I appreciate any help given!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it easier to do this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".download .dl").click(function(){
        $('#file-link').attr('href', $(this).next("input").val());
        $('#popup').bPopup();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Something like this...

```
 $("div[id*='downloadLink']").click(function () {
          $('#file-link').attr('href',$(this).siblings('img').attr('src'));
          $('#popup').bPopup();
});
```

After a click on any download link, this code will pass the associated image href path to the file-link element.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RqDD/1/) is the working fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would've selected yours as the answer but Niels' was more relevant due to the .next() function I didn't know about. Thank you very much for your input though :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against using all those input fields. It just creates a bunch of unnecessary markup. Why not store the #count value simply in a JavaScript variable? And the inputs that contain the image paths could be removed as well. You could store that info in an attribute on each download link, named something like "data-path". For example:

```
<div id="downloadLink0" class="dl" data-path="/GetImage.ashx?path=/img/0.jpg">Download</div>
```

Now, going back to your original problem, the above markup would solve the issue quite easily:

```
$('.dl').click(function(){
    $('#file-link').attr('href', $(this).attr('data-path')); //could also do $(this).data('path') if using jQuery 1.6 or later
    $('#popup').bPopup();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people have already suggested different ways to achieve what you want, but nobody explained why your current code doesn't work.

The reason it currently doesn't work is because of how scope works in Javascript. There is no block scope* and so your `index` variable is defined once, and updated every time the loop runs, until in the end it has the maximum (last) value. Then whenever your event handler is run, `index` still has this value, and the last item will be used.

So, in JS, the easiest way to get a new scope is to use a closure. Here's an example adapted from your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < $("#count").val(); i++) {
    var fn = (function(index) {
      return function () {
          $('#file-link').attr('href', $('#hf' + index).val());
          $('#popup').bPopup();
      };
    })(i);
    $("#downloadLink" + i).click(fn);
  }     
});
```

This is not as good a way to solve your actual problem as some of the other answers. However, it demonstrates the concept of creating a scope: you're calling a function that takes one parameter, `index`, for which you pass the loop iterator variable `i`. This means that the function inside it (which it returns) can now always access the value of this parameter. The inner function gets stored in `fn`, which then gets passed as the click handler.

If this looks really tricky, here's [a more in-depth look at function and scope in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

*Note that proposed new versions of Javascript/Ecmascript may add block scoped variables. It is not currently implemented in a cross-browser fashion, however.

Comment: Thanks Gijs, I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably calculate it from the event source (#downloadLinkn), by getting *n* from the end of the string.